# google translator JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internationalization, google-translate

How to translate English langauge text to a foreign language with google translator via JavaScript without showing a google toolbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [page from Google Language API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

Caution about Google API!

You can send no more then 5000 symbols for translation. And after some requests (about 500) you will be simply banned.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

add meta tag is header

```
<meta name="google-translate-customization" content="b6703fd8b1d84044-bd4dd2611d59f8dc-g6a8fe920a18c8f60-d"></meta>
```

add belo code where do you want

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```